# Div overflow scroll with scroll control - JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a div that has content loaded into it. If the user tries to load different content into it I want the div to scroll to the top of itself first. This cannot be achieved by anchor tags and needs a bit of JQuery.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: "If the user tries to load different content into it I want the div" -- what does this mean?

Comment: What do you have, what is the problem, etc.? Add some code example first.

Answer (score 3):

Just call scrollTop on the element:

```
$('#scrollable_div').scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: Thank you. I can except your answer in 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) will be your best friend for doing something like this